# Boxplot how to set the xlim

Tags: r, boxplot, x-axis

I am trying to make a box plot with the following code

```
boxplot(depy ~ depx, outline = FALSE, ylim = c(-20,20))
```

which works fine

[image]

When I try to add a limit for the x-axis

```
boxplot(depy~depx,outline=FALSE,xlim=c(-10,10),ylim=c(-20,20))
```

I get this

[image]

which looks like it has a wrong scale and doesn't show the tick marks and axis labels outside the area with the plotted values.

Any help to fix this?

Comment: Check `?boxplot`. The x-axis variable is the grouping variable and it is usually a factor as mentioned in the documentation. Why would you need to set limits to the x-axis anyway? Above you do not see the scales and the tick marks because there are no categories with those numbers on the x-axis. I suggest you keep the first plot but if you really want to go with the second just add zeros for the values -20 to -5 and 7 to 20 on the x-axis.

Comment: @LyzandeR thanks for the explanation. I want to set the limits to compare different plots. I could add zeros as suggested but to me also the scale looks wrong (xlim=c(-10,10))

Comment: Add zeros, don't use the limit and it will be fixed on its own since the x axis is using categories (but I really think this is the wrong way)

Comment: The scale looks exactly like what I would expect.  The x-axis in your plot is showing factor levels, which are internally coded as integers, with 1 = "-6", 2 = "-3", 3 = "0", etc.  So when you change your x-limits to `c(-10, 10)`, you get -10 to 0 blank, 1-5 with your factor levels, and then 6-10 blank again.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments x-axis for boxplot is a grouping variable, and usually a factor.

We could extend it using *xlim* (I'd consider this **a wrong way**, but not impossible). In below example data, there are 3 groups (4=1, 6=2, 8=3), and if we want to extend it by 1 on both sides, we need to add 0th and 4th on x-axis:

```
#example data
d <- mtcars

#using xlim
boxplot(mpg ~ cyl, d, xlim = c(0, 4))
```

[image]

The better way is to fix the factor levels before plotting:

```
#better way using factor levels
d$cyl <- factor(d$cyl, levels = as.character(c(2, sort(unique(d$cyl)), 10)))
boxplot(mpg ~ cyl, d)
```

[image]